# How to show progress bar when booting?

Tags: 12.04, boot

When I boot Ubuntu 12.04, the progress-bar shows for only a few seconds, then the screen's background becomes a blank brown image for a long time (not a constant time), then it goes black for a few seconds. At last the desktop shows.

I feel bad when screen goes blank. How to show progress bar all the time when booting?

Comment: The answer to this may be specific to your graphics hardware, and the driver you're using.  Just in case it is, could you list these?  Also, if you have done any customisations to your boot (including your grub configuration) or xorg.conf.

Comment: As far as I know, there has never been a progress bar. Fedora has something that looks like a progress bubble, but not Ubuntu.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.